# Outlook Addin Email Template Duplicative Flow

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

In the Outlook Addin, when you select Email Templates and then select a Lightning email template category, you are required to select an object type (related to), which filters the email templates returned.

Once you select an email template, you are required to provide both the contact to populate the email template AND an object record.  To do the latter, you must select the type of object (related to).  But this is duplicative, because you previously selected a type of object to filter the email templates.

Why are you asked to select the type of object twice and can this be avoided so you only need to do so once?

Also, when you do select the object type the second time, the list of objects returned is NOT limited to objects associated with the selected contact.  Is there any way to limit the objects to the contact?